# Second parameter on window.location.href gets NULL on Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So Im trying to discern why the second parameter that calls a certain method of my controller gets NULL, this is the code that I have on my cshtml:

```
$("#aceptarBorrar").click(function () {
    debugger;
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("BajaServAsoc", "ServiciosAsoc")' + '?CodServ=' + codSerElim, + '?CodServAsoc=' + codSerAsElim;
        });
```

At this point in the debugger both my variables have values.

But at this point:

```
public ActionResult BajaServAsoc(string CodServ, string CodServAsoc)
{
    try
    {

        string usuario = SessionHelpers.DatoPuente.UsuarioLegajo;
        ServiciosAsocNegocio SerANeg = new ServiciosAsocNegocio();
        SerAsociado ServA = new SerAsociado()
        {
            CodServ = CodServ,
            CodServAsoc = CodServAsoc,
            User = usuario
        };
        SerANeg.BajaServAsoc(ServA);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

The value is lost and I dont get why, I dont know where is losing it's value, why not both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of errors here:

```
'?CodServ=' + codSerElim, + '?CodServAsoc=' + codSerAsElim;
```

First, en errant comma is a syntax error.  Just get rid of it entirely:

```
'?CodServ=' + codSerElim + '?CodServAsoc=' + codSerAsElim;
```

Second, the resulting URL doesn't have two valid parameters, only one.  Use an `&` to add further URL parameters:

```
'?CodServ=' + codSerElim + '&CodServAsoc=' + codSerAsElim;
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I certainly check kiziu webpage

Answer (score 2):

You have two ? in your query string. The second one should be an & symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is not formed properly. Question mark `?` should only be used once, to indicate the beginning of query string. Values (pairs) are concatenated using ampersand `&` and each key/value pair is concatenated using equals sign `=`.

For more information take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string